# How to make an object parent to a vertex of another object

Tags: vertices, parent

Suppose you have three cube objects. Is it possible to make one vertex of the first cube child to the second cube, and another vertex child to the third cube?

This would mean that if you move the second and/or third cube, the first cube is being deformed.

So the general question is: **you can make a vertex parent to an object, but can you also make an object parent to a vertex**?

Comment: Look for a "Hook" modifier.

Comment: That did the job. Thx.